# Emacs lua-mode syntax highlighting not working

Tags: emacs, lua

I installed the lua-mode for Emacs 24.1 but when I am writing lua code, the syntax highlighting is not working properly.

lua-mode does not recognize a comment starting with '--'. And even single quoted strings like 'string' are also not highlighted.

I could not find any specific information about this particular issue, does anyone has any idea what is going on?

Comment: The problem is happening on all the OS I work with (windows, mac, linux) I am using Emacs package manager to install the lua-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlighting works for me on GNU Emacs 24.1.50.1A. A couple of things for you to double check:

- Is lua-mode enabled (the word "Lua" should appear in the mode line). If not, try to activate it manually via `M-x lua-mode` on a file buffer containing lua code.
- Is `lua-mode.el` current? I use version 20111107 from http://immerrr.github.com/lua-mode.

Answer (score 0):

using ubuntu 12.04 i installed emacs 24 by doing this:

```
  $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cassou/emacs
  $ sudo apt-get update
  $ sudo apt-get install emacs-snapshot-el emacs-snapshot-gtk emacs-snapshot
```

i dont remember if lua-mode was installed right away, but i am using https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit and installed it via "package-install lua-mode" from inside of emacs.

if you have trouble, maybe some old emacs settings cause them. to be sure, delete ~/.emacs.d and other ~/.emacs stuff.

Comment: Syntax highlighting is partially working. the single line comment and single quote strings are not working. Can you confirm that they are properly highlighted on your Ubuntu box?